# hide radio buttons on change

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

i have three radio buttons like a b c and i want that if i click on b, three more radio buttons become visible below. i have written code for radio buttons but i don't know to hide and show those radio buttons which are below on change. i have tried this way but could not get it done

```
$(document).on('change','#quarterly',function(){
    $("input:radio[name='FIRST'],input:radio[name='SECOND']").hide();
});
```

quarterly is id of that button on which i want to change
Please help!!!!!
Here is the html

Period
        
            Yearly  
            Quarterly  
            Monthly  
            Period

First
        
                                    
                                
                                                
          Second   
                        
                              
    
       
          Third

Comment: can you show us any html?

Comment: @Dekel that did not work for me

Comment: @DanishBhatti, did you run the example?

Answer (score 3):

I tired this and it worked!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Radio Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#buttonsClick").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){

            $("#buttonsClick").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div id="buttonsClick">
        <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red
        <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green
        <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

while the document is loaded, hide the div containing radio buttons as shown in the example and onclick function of the element use .show() property and the work is done!

Answer (score 2):

A few things to notice:

1. There is no `:radio` css selector.
2. Usually when we work with `radio` buttons we don't use ids (but names) because they way we group radio buttons is by their name.
3. It's better to check the actual value (using `$(this).val()`).

Here is a working example:

```js
$(document).on('change','input[type=radio][name=opt]',function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'opt2') {
    $("input[type='radio'][name='FIRST'],input[type='radio'][name='SECOND']").show();
  } else {
    $("input[type='radio'][name='FIRST'],input[type='radio'][name='SECOND']").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
input[name='FIRST'], input[name='SECOND'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="opt" type="radio" value="opt1" checked="checked" /> opt1 <br />
<input name="opt" type="radio" value="opt2" /> opt2 <br />
<input name="FIRST" type="radio" /> <br />
<input name="SECOND" type="radio" /> <br />
```

Comment: @ImranQamer, the html in the question was posted about an hour after my answer was here :) this answer is generic (without the information provided by the OP).

Comment: in html posted in question there is no radio with name FIRST,SECOND , I think so your solution will not work for above scenario.

Comment: Ok, I am seing now html is not there aswell.

Comment: I think so @Danish Bhatti is starter

Answer (score 0):

use this Code

```
$(document).on('change','#quarterly',function(){
    $("#FIRST").parent(".row").hide();
    $("#SECOND").parent(".row").hide();
    $("#THIRD").parent(".row").hide();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('change','#quarterly',function(){
    $("#FIRST").closest(".row").hide();
    $("#SECOND").closest(".row").hide();
    $("#THIRD").closest(".row").hide();
});
```

Because in your case `FIRST,SECOND,THIRD` are IDs not names.